# Looping through CSV file but getting duplicate results Python 3 / Selenium / BS4

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have a csv file that has two URL's (potentially 100's). I'm trying to open each link in an existing browser (for login reasons) and print the URL and print the scraped Address. The URL is printing correctly but the address prints as the first address every time. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)

source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

with open('UTlinks.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        driver.get(line)
        address = soup.find('span', class_='street-address').get_text()
        print(line + address)
```

output:

```
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/175-E-600-N-84664/home/81569604
175 E 600 N 
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/1918-W-800-N-84664/home/103092024
175 E 600 N
```

Desired output:

```
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/175-E-600-N-84664/home/81569604
175 E 600 N 
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/1918-W-800-N-84664/home/103092024
1918 W 800 N
```

Comment: how does the csv file look? do yo have each url saved on seperate line or seperated by a delimiter ?

Comment: No header, just the URL's in the first column

Comment: @RyanEvans check my below answer. you know that you even was could do this from the previous script which i wrote. i meant that you even was don't need to collect urls then loop back again to collect address ! you was can do it from the start.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, yeah, that one works great. The problem is I can get the URL's just fine without logging in. Once I visit the URL, I need to be logged in to get the additional information. I tried opening firefox and keeping an instance of it logged in but your code uses a different instance and gives me "not logged in" results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import io
from selenium import webdriver

f = io.StringIO("""https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/175-E-600-N-84664/home/81569604
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/1918-W-800-N-84664/home/103092024
""")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for url in f.readlines():
    url = url.rstrip()
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.street-address").text
    print(f"{driver.current_url}\n{element}")
```

Comment: This works however, the URL's will change so I need to pull from a .csv file. I also need to use the same browser so I'm logged in. I will be grabbing more than the address and being logged in gives me access to more.

Comment: @RyanEvans are you really will use selenium for this ?

Comment: I suppose I don't need too. I'm very new and like to visually see it working. The other issue is the login. If i use the same browser, I stayed logged in and have access to more information.

Comment: @RyanEvans check my updated answer. that should open each url in new tab within the same window, leaving for you the first one empty to be logged in :P

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks again αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη

Answer (score 0):

If you have urls on seperate lines from csv file, try this approach,

```
    import csv

       chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)

with open('UTlinks.csv') as file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file)
    for row in readCSV:
        url = str(row).replace("['","").replace("']","")
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
        html_content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
        address = soup.find('span', class_='street-address')
        print(address.text)



driver.quit()
```

**Here is the output:**

```
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/175-E-600-N-84664/home/81569604 175
E 600 N 
https://www.redfin.com/UT/Mapleton/1918-W-800-N-84664/home/103092024
1918 W 800 N
```

Comment: throws a 'Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string'

Comment: I have changed the logic little bit. it is now printing the addresses from each url correctly.